# Two words related to "anachronism" but having exclusive references to past and future

Tags: tenses, past-tense, time, future

I'd like to identify two words related to *anachronism*: one having an exclusive association to *past*, and the other to *future*.

[According to Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anachronism), *anachronism* means:

> A thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in which it exists, especially a thing that is conspicuously old-fashioned

I realize that in common usage, *anachronism* typically refers to the past because time travel to the past violates our current understanding of physics—however, I'm looking for words that are exclusive to *past* and *future*, respectively.

---

Edit: Adding more clarity to the question, via [@FumbleFingers' comment below](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538213/two-words-related-to-anachronism-but-having-exclusive-references-to-past-and-f#comment1317769_538213): I want to

> split **anachronisms** into two "subtypes". One where the "anachronistic" thing appears at an inappropriately **early** time (soldiers in the Roman empire using machine-guns, say). The other where something appears **later** than its "proper" time...

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to split ***anachronisms*** into two "subtypes". One where the "anachronistic" thing appears at an inappropriately ***early*** time (soldiers in the Roman empire using machine-guns, say). The other where something appears ***later*** than its "proper" time - for which I can't think of an obvious example that actually ***happens***, because if it was something we were familiar with it wouldn't really be anachronistic. But *hypothetically*, I suppose if US Marines start building ballistae along the border with Mexico, that would count.

Comment: But as regards *actual future* (later than ***now***), it's hard to see how anything could fit. Since we don't *know* what the future will bring, we can't know what belongs there rather than in the present day or earlier.

Comment: In common parlance: **throwback** or, **dinosaur** for something from the past. ("**Antediluvian**" if you want to sound fancy) The opposite: **Futuristic** is easily understood. AmE

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that’s what I’m looking for.

Comment: 'Parachronism' is sometimes cited as an antonym of 'anachronism', but 'anachronysm' _is_ ill-defined.

Comment: Just to point out that you don’t need a time machine to get things from the future into a current or past setting,  just make a gladiator movie and leave a cellphone on the table.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very good reason why the word *anachronism* is as it is.  Its standard or most basic application is to mistakes which are the effects of ignorance or carelessness.  For example, the recasting of Shakespearean plays in modern dress is not generally regarded as 'anachronistic', because the 'out of place' assault rifles etcetera are deliberate and so, even by its critics, just bad taste.

Even if that were not so, the idea of 'prochronism', though the best stab at a word, has very little to apply to.  In the sense discussed, we lack the knowledge of the future to have something obviously 'out of place'.  At least, it could only happen where a play or story about the past introduced something belonging to a later time (but still in the past).

Such an example can occur where someone is trying to convey, speaking of Shakespeare, tutor English, but includes a word or a phrase that belongs to the Jacobean period, or if a description of a meal eaten by Roman soldiers at Vindolanda on Hadrian's wall included tomatoes.  These would be called anachronisms, and for which you want to coin a term like, say, *prochronism*, and refer to having parliamentary forces in the British civil war bombarding royalist Oxford's defences with catapults or arquebuses as a *metachronism*.

I very much fear that even if such someone adopted a distinction as between *prochronism/metachronism*, it would have far to few contexts for its use for the distinction to catch on and become a standard usage.

Answer (score -2):

Jesus with a computer, and me with a time-machine are both anachronisms. Anachronisms are things that are outside their time frame, both past and future.

Lexico is lacking in its defintiond of **anachronism**. It has one meaning and two senses:

OED

> **1. An error in computing time, or fixing dates; the erroneous reference of an event, circumstance, or custom to a wrong date. Said etymologically (like prochronism) of a date which is too early, *but also used of too late a date*, which has been distinguished as parachronism.**

> 1705   T. Hearne Ductor Historicus (ed. 2) I. i. i. 8   *Virgil by making Dido and Æneas Co-temporaries, whereas they lived at Three Hundred Years distance..committed an Anachronism.*

> **2**. Anything done or existing out of date; hence, anything which was proper to a former age, but is, or, *if it existed, would be, out of harmony with the present*; also called a practical anachronism. Also transf. of persons.

> 1952   M. McCarthy Groves of Academe iii. 37   *She herself was a smoldering anachronism, a throwback to one of those ardent young women of the Sixties, Turgenev's heroines.*

Comment: You with a time machine is the same sort of anachronism as Jesus with a computer  since the time machine hasn't been invented yet. A better answer would be you, in your twenty-first century home, using a candlestick phone with no dial to make a routine call and having to ask the operator to connect you.

Comment: @BoldBen That is covered in 2. OED.

Comment: This doesn't seem to attempt to address my question.

Comment: @jsejcksn *I'd like to identify the words related to anachronism, but having specific meaning to past and future*  I answered *Anachronisms are things that are outside their time frame, both past and future.* What is lacking?

Comment: The question title: "Two words related to “anachronism” but having exclusive references to past and future" and the final summary: "I'm looking for words that are exclusive to _past_ and _future_, respectively". The "two words" and "**exclusive** to _past_ and _future_, respectively" aspects are key to the answer I'm seeking.

Comment: @jsejcksn I think you need to give examples and context.

Comment: Do *prochronism* and *parachronism* fit the requirement?

Comment: @Greybeard I have updated the question with more support to clarify

Comment: @AndrewLeach I read the sections describing those words at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism before posting this question, but they aren't quite what I'm looking for. They describe the possibility of existence related to time, but I'm looking for words that describe appropriateness in time (definitely allowing for possibility of existence).

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks. I think we are halfway there: *The other where something appears later than its "proper" time...* E.g. an advanced society in which interplanetary travel is common but the television has only just been invented and is low-quality, black and white?

Comment: @Greybeard I think that would fit!

Comment: @jsejcksn OK, you now need to give the sentence in which the word would appear.

Comment: Ok, here’s the example sentence from the Lexico link: _everything is as it would have appeared in centuries past apart from one **<past type of anachronism>**, a bright yellow construction crane_

Comment: @jsejcksn *"everything is as it would have appeared in centuries past apart from one **anachronism**, a bright yellow construction crane.* The correct word is **anachronism**.

Comment: @Greybeard I wasn't saying that there was anything wrong with the definition, just pointing out that both the OP's examples work in the same direction (that is the technology post dates the person using it) whereas my example works in the opposite direction (that is the technology has gone out of use before the time at which it is being used).